# Getting TIME without converting it to local time zone

Tags: c#, datetime

Proxy code reads DATETIME("2016-05-08T12:33:11.991-05:00") from XML, and then creates DateTime object. Then my code reads the DateTime. I would like to get the TIME as it was in XML file but without TZ ("2016-05-08 12:33:11.991000"). How do I get that?

(Note that I do not have access to the code used for creating DateTime object from XML file. DateTime.Kind says LOCAL.)

psuedocode

```
Input-XML  "2016-05-08T12:33:11.991-05:00". //Creates DateTime object called DtXML.
.....
I do not have access to this code.
.....

DtXML.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff"); //This gives 2016-05-08   10:33:11.991000
DtXML.Kind;// This is LOCAL.

I want to get "2016-05-08 12:33:11.991000".
Is this possible?
```

Comment: I know that is incorrect value, but that is what enduser expects.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DateTimeOffset` and do this.

```
string s = "2016-05-08T12:33:11.991-05:00";
var dtOffset =DateTimeOffset.Parse(s, null);

DateTime dt = dtOffset.DateTime; // 08.05.2016 12:33:11
Console.WriteLine(dtOffset.DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff")); // prints - 2016-05-08 12:33:11.991000
```

Check this [`code`](http://rextester.com/PPWUA64493)

Comment: I saw this answer this an another post. This does not apply to me. This example is able to initialize the DateTimeOffset object. In my case I do not have control over initialining DateTime object that I am consuming. Some other code reads the 'Date-time' from XML and creates DateTime object. I am just consuming that DateTime object.

Comment: So the question shold be how to convert `DateTime` to corresponding timezone's `DateTime` (may be client timezone in thiscase)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
var expectedDT = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DtXML.ToUniversalTime(), DateTimeKind.Local);
```